# Python Generator: How do I generate pairs from two different lists based on user input (of how many pairs to print)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, generator

Given there is are two lists:

```
colorList1 = ['red', 'orange', 'pink', 'brown', 'green', 'yellow']
colorList2 = ['purple', 'blue', 'violet', 'black, 'cyan', 'white']
```

How do I generate and print 1 color from each list (per row), starting from beginning of list, based on the number entered by the user. And, how do I generate only a maximum of 2 pairs of colors each time until user hits Enter key.

Example:

```
userinput = int(input("Enter a limit: "))  # user enters 5
```

Output:

```
red     purple
orange  blue       
press Enter key for next 2 pairs of colors     # user presses Enter key to generate the next pair
pink    violet
brown   black      
press Enter key for next 2 pairs of colors     # user presses Enter key to generate the next pair
green   cyan              # last pair since user entered 5
End of list of colors
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this.

```py
colorList1 = ['red', 'orange', 'pink', 'brown', 'green', 'yellow']
colorList2 = ['purple', 'blue', 'violet', 'black', 'cyan', 'white']

def print_color():
    userInput = input("Enter amount to print: ")

    try:
       userInput = int(userInput)
    except ValueError:
        print("User Input must be a positive integer")
        return

    if userInput < 0:
        print("User Input must be a positive integer")
        return

    for i in range(0, int(userInput)):

        if i >= len(colorList1) or i >= len(colorList2):
            print("End of list of colors")
            return

        if i % 2 == 0 and i != 0:
            input("press Enter key for next 2 pairs of colors")

        print(colorList1[i], colorList2[i])

print_color()
```

EDIT: I have updated the code to include basic error checking

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
colorList1 = ['red', 'orange', 'pink', 'brown', 'green', 'yellow']
colorList2 = ['purple', 'blue', 'violet', 'black', 'cyan', 'white']
color_pairs = iter(zip(colorList1,colorList2))
userinput = int(input("Enter a limit: "))  # user enters 5
i = 0
while i<userinput:
    if i%2 == 0: input(f"press Enter key for next 2 pairs of colors")
    print(*next(color_pairs))
    if i+1 == len(colorList1):
        break
    i += 1
print("\nEnd of list of colors")
```

Output:

```
Enter a limit: 5

press Enter key for next 2 pairs of colors
red purple
orange blue

press Enter key for next 2 pairs of colors
pink violet
brown black

press Enter key for next 2 pairs of colors
green cyan

End of list of colors
```

## limit = 7:

```
Enter a limit: 7

press Enter key for next 2 pairs of colors
red purple
orange blue

press Enter key for next 2 pairs of colors
pink violet
brown black

press Enter key for next 2 pairs of colors
green cyan
yellow white

End of list of colors
```